# How to pass variables from one method to another method in Struts Action Class?

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I have an action class with multiple action methods. Assume I have the following code:

```
public class FooAction extends ActionSupport {

//Service obj
private FooService fooService;
private Foo foo;
private String fooName;

public String findFoo() {
    foo = fooService.findFoo(fooName);
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String deleteFoo() {
    // fooService.deleteFoo(fooName);
    return SUCCESS;
}

// getters + setters
```

After calling the `findFoo()` method to find an object, the user decides to delete this object and the `deleteFoo()` method is called. However, this method fails because the `fooName` variable is reset to `null`.

How can I save the value of `fooName` variable before calling the `deleteFoo()` method?

Many thanks

Comment: How it is reset to null?Could't understand your question exactly.

Comment: In the findFoo() method the user inputs the value of the fooName variable. This value is saved just for the findFoo() method thus, in the deleteFoo() method it is null.

Comment: Actions are created and destroyed with each HTTP request.

Comment: I know that. I am trying to save the value of fooName variable which is created in the findFoo() method and then pass it to deleteFoo() to proceed to the following action. Is that possible?

Comment: Why user is finding object before deleting, you can write a single method for same, Don't return from findfoo(); just call it from deletefoo.

Comment: In my application after the object is found, the user can choose whether to delete or edit this object. If the user decides to delete/edit this object, another action is called. That's why I have to separate methods mate.

Comment: Why can't you send object name again, when you call deletefoo() method?Any how are you handling it at gui? let me know flow on gui in brief?

Comment: search > foo object > (textfield for fooName) > submit > foo object displayed > delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put that variable into action context and get it in any other method by using action context. Or implement `SessionAware` interface in your class.

Comment: Thank you... I have used the SessionAware interface and it works like a charm.